# Get links with specific words from a HTML code in C#

Tags: c#, regex, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse a website. I need some links in HTML file which contains some specific words. I know how to find "href" attributes but I don't need all of them, is there anyway to do that? For example can I use regex in HtmlAgilityPack?

```
HtmlNode links = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='navigation']/div/ul");

foreach (HtmlNode urls in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@]"))
{
    this.dgvurl.Rows.Add(urls.Attributes["href"].Value);
}
```

I'm trying this for finding all links in HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an HTML file like this:

```
<div class="a">
    <a href="http://www.website.com/"></a>
    <a href="http://www.website.com/notfound"></a>
    <a href="http://www.website.com/theword"></a>
    <a href="http://www.website.com/sub/theword"></a>
    <a href="http://www.website.com/theword.html"></a>
    <a href="http://www.website.com/other"></a>
</div>
```

And you're searching for example the following words: `theword` and `other`. You can define a regular expression, then use LINQ to get the links with an attribute `href` matching your regular expression like this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(theworld|other)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

HtmlNode node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='a']");
List<HtmlNode> nodeList = node.SelectNodes(".//a").Where(a => regex.IsMatch(a.Attributes["href"].Value)).ToList<HtmlNode>();

List<string> urls = new List<string>();

foreach (HtmlNode n in nodeList)
{
    urls.Add(n.Attributes["href"].Value);
}
```

Note that there's a `contains` keyword with XPATH, but you'll have to duplicate the condition for each word you're searching like:

```
node.SelectNodes(".//a[contains(@href,'theword') or contains(@href,'other')]")
```

There's also a `matches` keyword for XPATH, unfortunately it's only available with XPATH 2.0 and HtmlAgilityPack uses XPATH 1.0. With XPATH 2.0, you could do something like this:

```
node.SelectNodes(".//a[matches(@href,'(theword|other)')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

I Find this and that works for me.

```
HtmlNode links = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='navigation']/div/ul");
    foreach (HtmlNode urls in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@]"))
        {
           var temp = catagory.Attributes["href"].Value;
           if (temp.Contains("some_word"))
              {
                dgv.Rows.Add(temp);
              }
        }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `HtmlNode links = ...;`? Should that statement be deleted?